# Can we join tables in CROSS APPLY?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, common-table-expression

My query is:

```
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT SUM(Payment)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(ABS(2)) Payment 
    FROM dbo.table1 
) AS T
) AS EC(ExpCalc)
```

I need something like this after join:

```
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT SUM(Payment)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(ABS(2)) Payment 
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
) AS T
) AS EC(ExpCalc) JOIN dbo.info i on t1.key = i.key
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't do what you want because you are not returning `key`.  But the bigger answer is that you can do a `join`, but you do it as a correlated subquery:

```
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT SUM(Payment)
 FROM (SELECT TOP(ABS(2)) Payment 
       FROM dbo.table1 t1
       WHERE t1.key = i.key
------^
      ) T
) AS EC(ExpCalc)
```

This would appear in a `FROM` clause like this:

```
FROM dbo.info i CROSS APPLY
(SELECT SUM(Payment)
 FROM (SELECT TOP(ABS(2)) Payment 
       FROM dbo.table1 t1
       WHERE t1.key = i.key
      ) T
) AS EC(ExpCalc)
```

Comment: i(dbo.info) is another table , where would you put it ?i think u have missed to mention that .